# getting value of a hidden cell of grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hiddenfield

I have a vb.net application in which a grid view is there with a hidden field. I want to get the value of that hidden cell

**Code behind**
statusGrdvw.Rows(assign).Cells(5).Text

Comment: Depends on wich framework version you use,  but i suggest you to use GridView.DataKey instead of this trick, it will help also to reduce page size and overall complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add this style in the html

```
<style>
.hidden {display:none;}
        #exportother {
            position: relative;
            top: 13px;
            left: -840px;
        }
    </style>
```

Then on the field you want to hide

```
ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden"
HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden"
```

The field will be hidden but will be accessible from code behind.

Comment: no problem :) if that is the solution pls mark it as a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much to go on but what you need to do is get it by its control index. So basically if you have 2 controls in one column you have a control at index 0 and index 1. Something like this (you'll have to look up the exact syntax):

```
((HiddenInput)statusGrdvw.Rows(assign).Cells(5).Controls[0]).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to fetch the value in hidden field :

```
Dim hidden2 As String  = CType(statusGrdvw.SelectedRow.Cells(5).FindControl("HiddenfieldID"), HiddenField).Value;
```